# Python machine learning linear regression numpy list error

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Having trouble understanding the errors and finding a solution to the errors. I am stuck. I am following a tutorial on https://pythonprogramming.net/forecasting-predicting-machine-learning-tutorial for machine learning and not so difficult linear regression. I've tried to change list to be immutable, but I think the difficulty of following along is the data that I'm collecting, seems to be very different from the data this tutorial is working with. I'm trying to use my own data. You can compare the codes from that site to the code here. What am I doing wrong?
How can I overcome this obstacle?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime
import math

style.use('ggplot')

df = {}

bid = []
btemp = []
ask = []
atemp = []
low = []
high = []
close = []

file=open("C:/documents/EURUSD.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)

for line in reader:
t=line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5],line[6],line[7],line[8]
    btemp = line[2] + line[3]
    bid.append(btemp)
    atemp = line[4] + line[5]
    ask.append(atemp)
    low.append(line[6])
    high.append(line[7])
    close.append(line[8])

bid.pop(0)
ask.pop(0)
low.pop(0)
high.pop(0)
close.pop(0)

nBid = [float(i) for i in bid]
nAsk = [float(i) for i in ask]
nHigh = [float(i) for i in high]
nLow = [float(i) for i in low]
nClose = [float(i) for i in close]

df['nClose'] = nClose

diffHighLow = [(x1 - x2) for (x1, x2) in zip(nHigh, nLow)]
sumBidAsk = [x1 + x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(nBid, nAsk)]
nSumBidAsk = []
for a in sumBidAsk:
    aTemp = (a / 2) * 100
    nSumBidAsk.append(aTemp)
df['HL_PCT'] = [x1 / x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(diffHighLow, nSumBidAsk)]

diffCloseBid = [(x1 - x2) for (x1, x2) in zip(nClose, nBid)]
divDiffCloseBid = [(x1 / x2) for (x1, x2) in zip(diffCloseBid, nBid)]
nPCT_change = []
for b in divDiffCloseBid:
    bTemp = b * 100
    nPCT_change.append(bTemp)
df['PCT_change'] = nPCT_change

df['forecast_col'] = df['nClose']
df['forecast_out'] = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))

df['laebl'] = df['forecast_col'].shift(-forecast_out)
X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
```

EDITED | Now including stack trace

```
File "<ipython-input-4-006cfd724c3e>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/venichhe/Desktop/test3.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/venichhe/Desktop')

File "C:\Users\venichhe\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\venichhe\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/venichhe/Desktop/test3.py", line 69, in <module>
df['laebl'] = df['forecast_col'].shift(-forecast_out)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

Comment: And what is the error? You have not specified it. Post it with complete stack trace.

Comment: I've edited post and included the stack trace. I was doing more research and I think I maybe using the pandas data frame the wrong way. I didn't get a chance to try that out yet, but I will, within the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try after correcting the spelling mistake:

```
df['**laebl**'] = df['forecast_col'].shift(-forecast_out)
```

to

```
df['label'] = df['forecast_col'].shift(-forecast_out)
```

Comment: And of course, first convert dict to a pandas data frame

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using a pandas dataframe at all, you're using a dictionary called df and then trying to use it like it's a dataframe. Try loading your data using [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: I was able to load the file, thank you. Now how do I select certain columns from the csv. I have tried using it like ['column'] as well as [column]. Neither work.